# Removing duplicates from a list which cannot be converted to set

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list which is the result of a function and the list is this :

```
lovers=[['Warner', 'Lugar'], ['Warner', 'Murkowski'], ['Warner', 'Smith'], ['Chambliss', 'Allard'], ['Chambliss', 'Isakson'], ['Lugar', 'Warner'], ['Lugar', 'Murkowski'], ['Lugar', 'Smith'], ['Murkowski', 'Warner'], ['Murkowski', 'Lugar'], ['Murkowski', 'Smith'], ['Allard', 'Chambliss'], ['Allard', 'Isakson'], ['Smith', 'Warner'], ['Smith', 'Lugar'], ['Smith', 'Murkowski'], ['Grassley', 'Talent'], ['Grassley', 'Bond'], ['Grassley', 'Allen'], ['Grassley', 'Roberts'], ['Talent', 'Grassley'], ['Talent', 'Bond'], ['Talent', 'Allen'], ['Talent', 'Roberts'], ['Durbin', 'Sarbanes'], ['Bond', 'Grassley'], ['Bond', 'Talent'], ['Bond', 'Allen'], ['Bond', 'Roberts'], ['Allen', 'Grassley'], ['Allen', 'Talent'], ['Allen', 'Bond'], ['Allen', 'Roberts'], ['Sarbanes', 'Durbin'], ['Roberts', 'Grassley'], ['Roberts', 'Talent'], ['Roberts', 'Bond'], ['Roberts', 'Allen'], ['Isakson', 'Chambliss'], ['Isakson', 'Allard']]
```

I want a to convert this list to a list where there are duplicates. i.e. if `['Warner', 'Lugar']` is there already then i don't want `['Lugar', 'Warner']`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `frozenset`:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(set(map(frozenset, lovers)))
set([frozenset(['Bond', 'Roberts']),
     frozenset(['Lugar', 'Smith']),
     frozenset(['Murkowski', 'Warner']),
     frozenset(['Allard', 'Chambliss']),
     frozenset(['Allen', 'Roberts']),
     frozenset(['Roberts', 'Talent']),
     frozenset(['Allard', 'Isakson']),
     frozenset(['Bond', 'Talent']),
     frozenset(['Lugar', 'Warner']),
     frozenset(['Allen', 'Talent']),
     frozenset(['Allen', 'Grassley']),
     frozenset(['Allen', 'Bond']),
     frozenset(['Smith', 'Warner']),
     frozenset(['Lugar', 'Murkowski']),
     frozenset(['Chambliss', 'Isakson']),
     frozenset(['Grassley', 'Roberts']),
     frozenset(['Murkowski', 'Smith']),
     frozenset(['Bond', 'Grassley']),
     frozenset(['Grassley', 'Talent']),
     frozenset(['Durbin', 'Sarbanes'])])
```

You could also use:

```
pprint(OrderedDict.fromkeys((map(frozenset, lovers))).keys())
```

Which preserves the order pairs, but arbitrarily picks only one value of the pairs. (You might also wish to consider an `OrderedSet` recipe instead of using `OrderedDict` if that's important).

Comment: I want to create a new list from lovers? Your code is removing the unwanted elements but there is no way of storing the list thus created. Basically I want the elements obtained by using frozenset to be stored in a list.

Comment: @VedGupta just use `[list(el) for el in set(map(frozenset, lovers))]` then... (or: `[map(list, set(map(frozenset, lovers)))]` or similar that takes your fancy)

Answer (score 0):

Use tupples instead of lists:

```
lovers=[('Warner', 'Lugar'), ('Warner', 'Murkowski'), ('Warner', 'Smith'), ... ]
```

Since tupples are immutables, you'll be able to convert the whole list to a set in order to remove the duplicates.

Comment: But tuples respect order: the OP wants ('Warner', 'Lugar') and ('Lugar', 'Warner') to be considered the same.

Comment: Lists are ordered too, aren't they ? But i see your point, i focused on the "can't convert to a set" problem and forgot the pair order one.

Comment: Yeah. It's unclear if the 'can't be converted to a set' is separate from the pair order problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't it be made into a set?

```
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    return set([tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in lst])
```

Using it:

```
>>> unique_lovers = sorted(remove_duplicates(lovers))
>>> for pair in unique_lovers:
    print pair

('Allard', 'Chambliss')
('Allard', 'Isakson')
('Allen', 'Bond')
('Allen', 'Grassley')
('Allen', 'Roberts')
('Allen', 'Talent')
('Bond', 'Grassley')
('Bond', 'Roberts')
('Bond', 'Talent')
('Chambliss', 'Isakson')
('Durbin', 'Sarbanes')
('Grassley', 'Roberts')
('Grassley', 'Talent')
('Lugar', 'Murkowski')
('Lugar', 'Smith')
('Lugar', 'Warner')
('Murkowski', 'Smith')
('Murkowski', 'Warner')
('Roberts', 'Talent')
('Smith', 'Warner')
```

The only "down-side" is that you lose the list order, and also the order of the lovers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the inner lists into frozensets, then convert the whole thing into a set:

```
frozenSetified = [frozenset(pair) for pair in lovers]
set(frozenSetified)
>>> {frozenset({'Allen', 'Bond'}), frozenset({'Roberts', 'Grassley'}), frozenset({'Isakson', 'Allard'}), frozenset({'Warner', 'Smith'}), frozenset({'Allen', 'Talent'}), frozenset({'Lugar', 'Smith'}), frozenset({'Murkowski', 'Lugar'}), frozenset({'Bond', 'Grassley'}), frozenset({'Talent', 'Grassley'}), frozenset({'Roberts', 'Bond'}), frozenset({'Murkowski', 'Warner'}), frozenset({'Roberts', 'Talent'}), frozenset({'Isakson', 'Chambliss'}), frozenset({'Sarbanes', 'Durbin'}), frozenset({'Allen', 'Grassley'}), frozenset({'Lugar', 'Warner'}), frozenset({'Murkowski', 'Smith'}), frozenset({'Allen', 'Roberts'}), frozenset({'Bond', 'Talent'}), frozenset({'Chambliss', 'Allard'})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use `set`:

```
newlist = list()
for item in lovers:
    if not filter(newlist.count,(item,item[::-1])):
        newlist.append(item)
print newlist
```

output:

```
[['Warner', 'Lugar'], ['Warner', 'Murkowski'], ['Warner', 'Smith'], ['Chambliss', 'Allard'], ['Chambliss', 'Isakson'], ['Lugar', 'Murkowski'], ['Lugar', 'Smith'], ['Murkowski', 'Smith'], ['Allard', 'Isakson'], ['Grassley', 'Talent'], ['Grassley', 'Bond'], ['Grassley', 'Allen'], ['Grassley', 'Roberts'], ['Talent', 'Bond'], ['Talent', 'Allen'], ['Talent', 'Roberts'], ['Durbin', 'Sarbanes'], ['Bond', 'Allen'], ['Bond', 'Roberts'], ['Allen', 'Roberts']]
```